# reflect.New returns <nil> instead of initialized struct

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, struct

I am using reflection for a library I'm building but there's something I don't understand about `reflect.New`.

```
type A struct {
    A int
    B string
}

func main() {

    real := new(A)
    reflected := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(real)).Elem().Interface()
    fmt.Println(real)
    fmt.Println(reflected)
}
```

Gives:

```
$ go run *go
&{0 }
<nil>
```

Isn't `reflect.New` supposed to return `&{0 }` too? ([Runnable Version](https://play.golang.org/p/6sHPbEoY9m))

Ultimately, I wish to be able to iterate over the fields of the reflected struct (`reflected.NumField()` gives `reflected.NumField undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`) and use `SetInt`, `SetString` and so on.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used the builtin [`new()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) function when you created your `real` variable, which returns a pointer! Type of `real` is `*A`, not `A`! This is the source of the confusion.

[`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) returns a pointer to the (zeroed) value of the given type (wrapped in a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect#Value)). If you pass the type `A`, you get back a wrapped `*A`, `A` initialized / zeroed. If you pass the type `*A`, you get back a wrapped `**A`, `*A` initialized (zeroed), and the zero value for any pointer type is `nil`.

You basically ask `reflect.New()` to create a new value of a pointer type (`*A`), and –as mentioned– its zero value is `nil`.

You have to pass the type `A` (and not the type `*A`). It works like this (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cB5GNPnXNW)):

```
real := new(A)
reflected := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(real).Elem()).Elem().Interface()
fmt.Println(real)
fmt.Println(reflected)
```

Or like this ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/m3e0TnICbo)):

```
real := A{}
reflected := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(real)).Elem().Interface()
fmt.Println(real)
fmt.Println(reflected)
```